# Change images automatically and count appeared image

Tags: android, mobile, imageview

I have a list of image URLs and have to show them and change them automatically in ImageView and need to count how many times every image appears to the user.

What could be the best approach to do this? can we avoid handlers here?

Answer (score 0):

Android provides views which can be used to display images from various sources and provide transitions between them. Some of these views are the ImageView and the ImageSwitcher. These views provide a high level of functionality to display images in a user interface so that we can concentrate on the images we want to display rather than taking care of rendering.
You can get complete guide setup in links description.
In description there is a complete explaination for changing image using ImageSwitcher
by pressing a button, But by updating the code to change after certain can be done easily.

Link to tutorial:
https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-displaying-images-android/

A github link for application used with image switching button:## Heading ##
https://github.com/Adarshgkp04/Android_Image_transitions.git

Feel free to ask queries.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Actually, I know about ImageSwitcher. 
What could be the best approach to handle auto-images-change and count image appearances to the user? I have some wired solutions using handler, add counters after comparing matched images etc but they are not good approach.